# How to remove this line in VSC..?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Could you please advise how to remove this line?
[image]

Comment: What is "this line"? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Please add all clarification to your question in text form

Comment: Could you open the link about 'enter image description here?

Comment: at what character count is the line?

Comment: How can I check that..?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: If you open the image by clicking the link beside my question; "enter image description here", there is a line to limit the number of characters and to move it to next line automatically once the code is over this line. I don't want to limit the number of characters or codes within this line. So, I want to know how to edit or remove this line in VSC setting. Guess it's due to word wrap?

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - don't use the comment section for important information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `rulers` in the settings pane. Then, from the link edit the .json file.
Or, directly add `.vscode/settings.json` under your project folder. And paste
this: `"editor.rulers": []`, leave it blank for hiding the visible right margin.